# mySQL tables get dropped un-intentionally

Tags: mysql, jpa, netbeans, ubuntu-14.04

In a development environment, where Ubuntu 14.04 installed and updated to Kubuntu 14.04 is used the operating system. MySQL installed and used with Netbeans and JPA using eclipselink. I noted that some tables are dropped without my knowledge and then I created users with no drop or delete privileges. When I log with mysql command, I can not delete tables. But tables are still get dropped intermittently ? What can be the cause? I am really worried as a very similar environment is used in production and a loss of a table can lead severe consequences.

Comment: clearly any JPA actions will be logged, but you don't mention even looking at the EclipseLink log

Answer (score 0):

Table just don't magically disappear.
If I was you, I'd start by getting the list of users having the rights to do the delete/drop table.
Ask them if anyone is working on the DDL.

If no one seems to be "guilty", then what about to check what logging possibilities are provided by your DBMS, and to what extent could you log drop operations.

Comment: This is my private machine. No one uses it except me. I have two mysql users. 'root'@'localhost' and 'buddhika'@'localhost'. Drop and Delete privileges are been revoked in root user. If I log as root from mySQL command prompt, I can not delete any table. I have given root login details to Netbeans. I use other account only when I want to use drop or delete. Still tables get dropped.

Comment: Using netbeans databases under services window definitely drop the database after certain unidentifiable occassions despite the use do not have the drop privilege. There must be a bug. But unfortunately no one except me is getting this error.

Comment: Error getting before dropping tables. Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
Error Code: 0